# Can I persist redis data in Oracle Database?

Tags: database-design, redis, in-memory-database

We are trying to implement caching through Redis I understand that it stores data into its own format RDB files. But we already have Oracle persistence which is used by other clients. So instead of storing in RDB files we would like to persist the data in Oracle DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the file writing in this case, and use Redis as a pure in-memory cache.
To do it just comment all the "save" lines in redis.conf.

In pseudo code, reading a value should be done like this:

```
result = get value from redis
if(result is null)
{
   result = get value from Oracle
   store result in redis
}
return result
```

**Update:** after some exchange in comments here is an alternative

Create a fake redis slave, which will connect to the Redis instance and then reproduce the write operations on the Oracle database. Look at redis documentation to see how replication works.

But it's not a trivial thing to do. You'll have to interpret Redis commands and apply corresponding SQL commands, and handle resynchronization when the Oracle Database fails. The performances will depend on the number of write operations. If they are too numerous, the Oracle database could not be able to cope with them. So once again, I don't think it's a recommended architecture.

Comment: We would like to persist the delta changes done in the Memory. Redis being the server which faces the clients which will update the data. All updates made to In-Memory has to be stored in DB at regular intervals. So the requirement is instead of regularly storing in RDB files we want to store it in Oracle. The first part is good for keys which are not available in Redis memory will be fetched from Oracle DB

Comment: Redis is not designed to store its data in another database, especially a relational one. The way you want to use it can only be achieved by writing you own replication code. By example you could parse redis log file with an app running in background, then write the data changes in Oracle. But I really not convinced by this way of doing things.

Comment: I was doing a comparing between Hazelcast and Redis.This is the only limitation I find with redis.The work around with log files doesn't seem feasible as we are looking at processing around 15k write/read requests per second. Hence scanning the information from file would be a very slow operation. Is it possible to know the changed keys during a particular duration when Redis starts writing into a file. I can probably catch hold of those keys and start writing in Oracle. Redis if I understand correctly keep track of number of keys changed but does it keep track of changed keys is my doubt.

Comment: As far as I know, you're right about tracking changes. I'll update my answer to give you another lead.